# CakePHP query closest latitude longitude from database

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, location, cakephp-3.0

In a CakePHP (v3) application, how can I retrieve the closest results based on passed lat lng values?

I'd like to have them back as native CakePHP entities, so something like this:

```
public function closest($lat, $lng) {

    $sightings = //records within given lat lng 

    $this->set(compact('sightings'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['sightings']);
}
```

I know this SQL works:

```
SELECT *,
       ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(50.7) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(-1.8) ) + sin( radians(50.7) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance
  FROM sightings
HAVING distance < 10
 ORDER BY distance
 LIMIT 0 , 20
```

Struggling to combine the two.

**UPDATE**

I've added

```
class Sighting extends Entity {
    public $_virtual = ['distance'];
    //rest of class...
}
```

So now the `distance` is showing up in my json output (with the value of null as would be expected right now, but I feel it's a step at lease).

I've taken a look here: http://www.mrthun.com/2014/11/26/search-distance-cakephp/ which seems to be what I'm trying to achieve so assumed something like this:

```
$latitude = 51.145;
$longitude = -1.45;
$distance = 100;

$this->Sightings->virtualFields
    = array('Sightings.distance'
     => '(3959 * acos (cos ( radians('.$latitude.') )
    * cos( radians( Sightings.latitude ) )
    * cos( radians( Sightings.longitude )
    - radians('.$longitude.') )
    + sin ( radians('.$latitude.') )
    * sin( radians( Sightings.latitude ) )))');

$sightings = $this->Sightings->find('all', [
    'conditions' => ['Sightings.distance <' => $distance]
]);

$this->set(compact('sightings'));
$this->set('_serialize', ['sightings']);
```

Results in: `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Sightings.distance' in 'where clause'`

Not sure if it's possible CakePHP v2 as opposed to v3?

Comment: That's my method so far, but I'm not doing any of the distance stuff, I'm unsure how to insert that sql into cakes way of doing it. 

public function findClosest($lat, $lng)
    {

        $sightings = $this->Sightings->find('all')
   ->where(['Sightings.created >' => new Time('-12 hour')])
   ->limit(5);

        $this->set(compact('sightings'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['sightings']);
    }

Comment: Tip: http://www.dereuromark.de/2012/06/12/geocoding-with-cakephp/

Comment: That is for cake 2.x, having trouble working it to 3.x

Comment: Please provide the SQL generated by CakePHP.

Comment: No, thats also for 3.x as you can see if you read it :) It will link to https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-geo which is a cake 3 plugin. It's also mentioned in the well known [awesome cakephp list](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/awesome-cakephp), which should always be your first stop before doing any other research.

Comment: This will cause the database engine to read every record and calculate the distance for every point in the entire database. You should compute a bounding box, eliminate all of the completely out of range points with > and < comparisons on latitude and longitude, then, for all the ones inside that box, do your distance calculation and `HAVING` filter them.

Answer (score 10):

there are no more virtualFields in cake 3 but you still can create an alias for your calculated field

As suggested by @ndm you'd better bind `$latitude` and `$longitude` to prevent SQL injections

```
$distanceField = '(3959 * acos (cos ( radians(:latitude) )
    * cos( radians( Sightings.latitude ) )
    * cos( radians( Sightings.longitude )
    - radians(:longitude) )
    + sin ( radians(:latitude) )
    * sin( radians( Sightings.latitude ) )))';
```

**using where**

```
$sightings = $this->Sightings->find()
    ->select([
        'distance' => $distanceField
    ])
    ->where(["$distanceField < " => $distance])
    ->bind(':latitude', $latitude, 'float')
    ->bind(':longitude', $longitude, 'float')
    ->contain(['Photos', 'Tags']);
```

**using having**

```
$sightings = $this->Sightings->find()
    ->select([
        'distance' => $distanceField
    ])
    ->having(['distance < ' => $distance])
    ->bind(':latitude', $latitude, 'float')
    ->bind(':longitude', $longitude, 'float')
    ->contain(['Photos', 'Tags']);
```

Comment: Please make sure to either explicitly cast or quote `$latitude` and `$longitude` in this example, or to use bindings, as otherwise this is a possible SQL injection vulnerability!

Comment: @ndm you are right. I will improve my answerin the next days

Comment: This is really close to what I need, it's selecting the correct rows, but it only seems to contain the distance value, is there a way to hydrate the entities as "Normal"?

Comment: You Can select all the fields you need of course. The manuale explains how to select all the fields of the model

Comment: try `->autoFields(true)` to select all the fields

Comment: There are still virtualFields in cake 3

Comment: No, there aren't (see this [**link**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/orm-migration.html#no-afterfind-event-or-virtual-fields)). They have been replaced by virtual properties (that you can't use in a query) or by custom finders. But you can't define a virtualField as a model's property as you used to do in cake2

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ConnectionManager here.

For example:

```
use Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager;  // Mention this first, preferably on top of the page.

$connection = ConnectionManager::get('default');

$results = $connection
  ->execute('SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id = :id', ['id' => 1])
  ->fetchAll('assoc');
```

You could try and set up your query in this fashion. It will definitely work.

Use this as a reference:

[SELECT Statements with CakePHP 3](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#running-select-statements)

Comment: That does work, thanks. Is there any way to include the ['contain' => ['Photos', 'Tags'] objects along with it or would I have to write the join?

This is basically the exact query...I just need to filter by the lat/lng 

public function index($lat, $lng)
    {

        $sightings = $this->Sightings->find('all', ['contain' => ['Photos', 'Tags']])
   ->where(['Sightings.created >' => new Time('-12 hour')])
   ->order(['Sightings.created' => 'ASC'])
   ->limit(5);

        $this->set(compact('sightings'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['sightings']);
    }

Comment: I think using join would be a better option. When you're using SELECT this way, it won't recognize the model associations, and therefore the usage of contain is skeptical.

Comment: It's kind of really close. I'm rendering the output as json and the problem is that the related tables are no longer displaying as related json objects. So for example the `id` in the join table is overwriting the `id` from the main primary table queried. This looks really close, https://gist.github.com/SwabTheDeck/0056d6785377d86deaa8 possibly looks like it's for cake 2.0 and I'm not sure how to implement it, and suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches to achieve your result.

#### 1. Raw Query

Instead of struggling with the ORM, you could perform a [raw query](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#creating-connections-at-runtime)?

```
$conn = ConnectionManager::get('my_connection');
```

And then you can run a custom query like:

```
$results = $conn->execute('MY RAW SQL HERE');
```

#### 2. Raw Query w/Eager loading

If you want to run a query and [eager load the relations](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#eager-loading-associations), you will need to use the contains method like:

```
$query = $articles->find('all', ['contain' => ['Authors', 'Comments']]);
```

#### 3. Using Virtual Fields

If you want to use virtual fields like in your example above, you need to add it in your entity model class like:

```
protected function _getDistance()
{
    //access model members using $this->_properties e.g.
    //return $this->_properties['latitude'] . '  ' .
    //    $this->_properties['longitude'];
}
```

This should ensure your distance is no longer null in your json.

And you could use with the distance method from [CakephpGeo library](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-geo/blob/master/src/Geocoder/Calculator.php#L106) to construct a query

```
public function distance(array $pointX, array $pointY) {
    $res = $this->calculateDistance($pointX, $pointY);
    return ceil($res);
}

public static function calculateDistance($pointX, $pointY) {
    $res = 69.09 * rad2deg(acos(sin(deg2rad($pointX['lat'])) * sin(deg2rad($pointY['lat']))
        + cos(deg2rad($pointX['lat'])) * cos(deg2rad($pointY['lat'])) * cos(deg2rad($pointX['lng']
        - $pointY['lng']))));
    return $res;
}
```

#### 4. Raw PHP

Lastly, and not recommended, you could retrieve all the info you need and use PHP to narrow down your results. Painful, slow and not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

finally i got the solution for this. below is the working example

```
$distance = 25;
$start_latitude = 12.920479;
$start_longitude = 77.670547;

$contents = $this->Sightings->find()->select(['latitude', 'longitude', 'distance' => 'SQRT(
    POW(69.1 * (latitude - '.$start_latitude.'), 2) +
    POW(69.1 * ('.$start_longitude.' - longitude) * COS(latitude / 57.3), 2))'])->having(["distance < " => $distance]);
```

output

```
   {"lat": xx.920479,
    "lng": xx.670547,
    "distance": "0"
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

People might want to look at the [CakePHP GeoDistance Plugin](https://github.com/chris48s/cakephp-geodistance):

> CakePHP-GeoDistance is a CakePHP 3 behavior for querying geocoded data based on cartographic distance using the spherical cosine law. It is great for 'find my nearest X' or 'find Y near me' type queries.

https://github.com/chris48s/cakephp-geodistance

Did the job.